# What category includes "news", "articles", and "stories"

Tags: vocabulary, hypernyms

I have created a dropdown menu for my website. In this dropdown menu I have put a tab for audio, a tab for video, but I don't know what to call the category that include (News, articles, and stories altogether). I'm looking for a word that says something like this: "The reading stuff found here". In other words, even though the word video includes many different subjects, someone understand this is a category that has all videos. Is there something similar for the reading part ?

Answer (score 2):

The word is [text](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/text?q=text)

> Written or printed words, typically forming a connected piece of work

Comment: Why not *print* to distinguish it from visual and auditory measures. While an emerging anacronism, most journalists who write consider their medium *print* not *text*.

Comment: Why restrict it to just what journalists do? If that's the case then *news*, *articles* and *stories* are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [print](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/print).

**print** (noun)

```
* printed material.
* a printed publication, as a newspaper or magazine.
```